# Instantiating a new component instance inside a conditional will be undefined

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

The following code will throw an undefined error, "Variable API is undefined":

```
public string function foo() {
    var bar = "";

    if (somecondition) {
        var api = new some.path.to.component();
        bar = api.baz();
    }

    return bar;
}
```

Whilst the following will work correctly:

```
public string function foo() {
    var bar = "";
    var api = new some.path.to.component();

    if (somecondition) {
        bar = api.baz();
    }

    return bar;
}
```

Trying to work around it by predefining the variable reveals it is not reassigned and will throw "Cannot invoke method find on an object of type java.lang.String":

```
public string function foo() {
    var bar = "";
    var api = "";

    if (somecondition) {
        api = new some.path.to.component();
        bar = api.baz();
    }

    return bar;
}
```

CF9.1 bug? Language feature? Obviously I only want to create the component if the conditional is true so although the latter works it feels a little wasteful.

Comment: Interesting - sounds like a bug

Comment: I'd be curious to see the actual code (including the init method from the component you're instantiating) rather than the foobarbaz stuff.

Comment: --> https://bugbase.adobe.com/ pls, thx

Answer (score 3):

For reference: I tested this in Coldfusion 9, and I'm not getting the error. I did add some component introspection and file existence check for graceful error handling

***page script***

```
somecondition = true;
public string function foo() {
    var bar = "unassigned";
    if (somecondition) {
        if(fileexists('/webroot/jquery/stackoverflow/test.cfc')){
            var api = new webroot.jquery.stackoverflow.test();
            var meta = GetMetaData(api);
            if(IsStruct(meta)){
                bar = api.test();
            }
        }
    }
    return bar;
}
WriteDump(var=foo());
```

***test.cfc***

```
  component displayname="test" output="false" {
    public string function test(){
        return 'foo test';
    }
   }
```

Seeing your actual code may assist in finding the issue.